# ASP NET MVC Не могу никак подключить Ajax хелперы

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Я уже все перепробывал! 
И создал *web.config*
и добавил в него:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

И подключил Jquery и Jquery-Ajax-Unobtrusive

```
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

И все равно когда я пишу:

```
@Ajax
```

Мне сообщают что такой команды нету!!! Я в шоке, что я делаю не так???

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, у Вас MVC 5 не Core. Во-вторых, если Вы хотите создать форму, то надо писать примерно так:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BookSearch", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results"}))
{
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Поиск" />
}
```

А просто AJAX нет. Это же хелперы, как HTML.

А если хотите писать JQuery, то в начале идёт `$`.

Вот Вам ссылка: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/10.2.php.

Comment: А тогда что такое  ASP.NET Core MVC? Разве Core не просто мультиплатформенность?

Comment: Конечно суть вопроса я не понял, но потому как задан вопрос, понимаю, что есть пробелы в знании самой платформы. Есть ASP.NET и ASP. NET Core. Они нужны для создания web - приложений. Но при создании приложения на основе mvc5 и mvc core, есть различия, процентов так на 30, и большинстве случаев это связано, в настройках и подключениях. И вашем вопросе явно видно что это mvc5  А когда говорят кроссплатформенность  то оно относится к самому ASP. NET Corу , а не его части в которой входит mvc.